# Invoke-WebReqeust - XML String needs to be stored in a form field called REQUEST and should be sent to our servers via HTTP POST method

Tags: powershell, webapi, invoke-webrequest

Stuck following some poor documentation. Attempting to connect to a vendors API to pull orders into my own DB. The vendor has only one line and example (not even a proper url that I am still attempting to get).

Documentation =
XML String needs to be stored in a form field called REQUEST and should be sent to our servers via HTTP POST method. All of the methods described in this document must follow this standard.

Example = 
GET ORDERS method XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrderXML>
 <Method>GET ORDERS</Method>
 <Authentication>
 <Username>Your Username</Username>
 <Password>Your Password</Password>
 </Authentication>
</OrderXML>
```

Tried in Postman and PowerShell just cannot figure out how to get "Request" form.
My code returns bad request and I am not sure if due to URL or not getting the "Request" form coded correctly.

```
$URI = "https://orders.website.com/webservice/default.cfm"
[xml]$requestXML = @'
    REQUEST=
    <OrderXML>
    <Method>GET ORDERS</Method>
    <TestMode>YES</TestMode>
    <Authentication>
    <Username>USERNAME</Username>
    <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
    </Authentication>
    </OrderXML>
'@
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -Method Post -Body $requestXML
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no way for us to test this out I'm afraid. Reading the poor description, I would think you need to wrap the XML **Text ONLY** inside a hashtable like `-Body @{REQUEST = $requestXML}`. Of course, get rid of REQUEST= in the xml text, and perhaps add the top line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Also make sure you remove `[xml]`.

Answer (score 0):

So finally figured it out in Postman.
Used the form control instead of Raw XML.
With Key being the required "REQUEST" and the Value being the XML.